# Updating arrayAdapter with new data in AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I have the following AsyncTask in my activity that updates an ArrayAdapter that populates my ListView. It seems to work ok because i call notifyDataSetChanged within the onPostExecute.

My question is why does it only update the listview if i call notifyDataSetChanged inside runOnUIThread with onPostExecute?

I thought that onPostExecute runs on the UIThread, so my do i need to wrap it in the Runnable?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(LoginWebservice.TwoDimentionalArrayList<String> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rotalist);

    arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(GetRota.this, array);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(GetRota.this);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even need to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  You are creating a new adapter and setting it to the `ListView`.  You make no modifications afterwards, so there's no need to call that method. It is redundant.

Comment: Yes you are correct, i've removed it and it still works. Is there any problem in creating a new adapter each time the data changes. The problem is, if no data comes back from the server then i display a different layout, so i set the listview and adapter to null. if a new call to server is called and this time it returns data, then i switch the layout back and re-instantiate the listview and adapter etc

Comment: Depends how often this is occurring. Whend setting a new adapter, all cached views and measurements get dumped. The ListView will create all new Views from scratch and possibly have to make some re-measurements (which causes a few dummy view generations to occur). Performance wise, it's better to clear then addAll...however if this is only a click a button and you reload data kinda thing...you're probably fine.

Comment: as a side note, ListView's support displaying an empty view when they are empty...of which you can customize. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)